# MS Access & Web browser Control is disabled

Tags: ms-access, vba, webbrowser-control, activex

I have a new Access 2016 database.  I add the reference to MS Internet Controls which basically makes the Web browser control available to place on a form, no problems works like a boss.

I have another Access database that has been converted to 2016 from 2013.  I add the reference but this time the control is disabled and won't allow me to place it on a form.

I am on the same machine so I don't believe the issue has to do with permissions/security (I could be wrong).  I am unable to find any info on this issue.

Comment: Are you using the ActiveX web browser control (found under Controls -> ActiveX controls -> Microsoft Web Browser) or the built-in web browser control? Are you using a continuous form? Is it really a form, and not a report?

Answer (score 1):

Resolution: Web browser control only works with ACCDB format.  My conversion was still using the mdb format.  Thanks for your response Erik.