# Access2019 webbrowsercontrol not displayed in ribbon toolbox

Tags: ms-access, webbrowser-control, ribbon, toolbox

I'm using A2019 32-bit and noticed that the control is not displayed in my Access DB for selection in the ribbon.
I created a test DB, in which the control is displayed and I can insert it in a form.
Is there any setting that I have overlooked?
Btw i don't want to use the ActiveX control with the similar name but the control in the toolbox...
thx

Answer (score 0):

solution:
change form property  from continuous form to single form

like mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839007/ms-access-web-browser-control-is-disabled) post:
(upps)